# Echo while using ear buds on my android phone

Tags: echo

All my app sounds and even my music has echo with my ear buds, without the ear buds it sound fine but for some reason when they are plugged in all sounds on my phone have echo. And yes they are plugged in all the way.

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You would have done well by reading the introductory [tour] which was offered when you signed up. Stack Overflow is a site for programmers and programming related questions. It looks like yours is not - possibly, the more general [Super User](http://superuser.com) can help you.